# How can programmatically check which version of the WMI is installed

Tags: c#, delphi, wmi

How can programmatically check which version of the [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx) (Windows Management Instrumentation) is installed using delphi or C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```cs
using System.Management;

ManagementObjectSearcher query = new
    ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_WMISetting") ;
ManagementObjectCollection items = query.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject mo in items)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(mo["BuildVersion"]);
}
```

There should only be one thing in the `items` collection since that setting is a singleton. "BuildVersion" is the WMI version that is installed.

EDIT:

Helen's comment below gives an even more succinct solution:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(
       (new ManagementObject("Win32_WMISetting=@"))["BuildVersion"]);
```

Comment: +1 the `Win32_WMISetting` class retrieves the info about the version of the WMI.

Comment: Since `Win32_WMISetting` is a singleton, you can simply use `(new ManagementObject("Win32_WMISetting=@"))["BuildVersion"]`.